How do one test for absence of performance drop?
I'll try to keep this general... Say I calibrate a Supervised ML model and observe some performance locally (in and out of sample). Then I put the model into production and observe some 'live' performance.
Some additional note:

By performance I mean either the loss (log-loss, MSE) or some metric (AUC)
The performance observed locally (in and out of sample) is observed from a data split (model is calibrated on 60% of data and tested on 40% of out of sample data), or a repeated split (k-fold, potentially shuffled), giving some sample of in and out of sample performance.

I want to test:

if out-of-sample performance is lower than in-sample performance (overfitting)
if live performance is lower than out-of-sample performance (live performance degradation)

Is there a formal framework for testing (the absence of) performance loss ?
